# Why the any point has same magnitude of electric line of force?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, symmetry

[image]

The $n~$ point charges have been placed on the same straight line.

$\theta_{i}:=\text{angle between 2 line segments of point A like shown as the above diagram.}$

We want to deduce the below equation of electric lines of force.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} q_{i}\cos(\theta_{i})=\text{constant value}\tag{1}$$

$$\text{For any set of angles.}$$

If I've get the problem statement correctly, the any point on the **one**
electric line of force has the same magnitude.

The blue and the green lines constitute the circles. Each surface of it is vertical against the line segment of n point charges.

$\omega_{i}=2\pi(1-\cos(\theta_{i})):=\text{solid angle from ith point.}$

The number of the electric lines of force which emanates from the ith point charge is $\frac{q_{i}}{\epsilon_{0}}$

So ith point charge's number(or magnitude) of the electric lines of force  which penetrate the surface of the blue circle is given as below.

$$\frac{q_{i}}{\epsilon_{0}}\frac{\omega_{i}}{4\pi}=\frac{q_{i}(1-\cos(\theta_{i}))}{2\epsilon_{0}}\tag{2}$$

From the principle of superposition, the total number of the electric lines of force which penetrate the blue surface is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{q_{i}(1-\cos(\theta_{i}))}{2\epsilon_{0}}\tag{3}$$

We assume the green circle so that the electric lines of blue circumference pass the green circumference.

Since an electric line cannot intersect with another electric line, any electric line which penetrates blue surface penetrates the green surface.

So the below equation is held of the any point on the electric line.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{q_{i}(1-\cos(\theta_{i}))}{2\epsilon_{0}}\leftarrow\text{constant}\tag{4}$$

Currently I can't get the above statement. Why this claim can be adequate?

Should I consider pairwise circles? What should I consider for next?